# Setting custom headers on client side to be retrieved by server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, request-headers

I am creating a sort of authentication system, where a pop up opens, a user authenticates, the page closes, and a script retrieves all the users data from a database.

A function on the client side is supposed to set headers for the website using the authentication, then refresh it so that the headers can be accessed by a server.

There are multiple constraints

1. I can not just send a POST request to the server with the headers as the request body.

This is because the script is meant to be used by others and I want it to be as simple as possible (the dev shouldn’t have to create a bunch of POST endpoints or anything like that. I’m going for something like `request.headers[“auth_username”]`.

I did some research on this and found the `Headers` API, and I tried that- this isn’t working for some reason because when I log all the headers on the server side I just get the default ones.

Here is my code:

```js
const h = new Headers();
var authWindow;
window.addEventListener("message",(data)=>{
  h.set("so-auth-user",data.display);
  h.set("so-auth-email", data.email);
  h.set("so-auth-name", data.fName + " " + data.lName);
  setTimeout(()=>{authWindow.close()},500);

  location.reload();
})
```

The event listener just listens for the data sent by the pop up.

One thing that I immediately notice is that the Headers object is never acted upon. As far as my understanding goes, all the Header interface does is create a string with all of the headers… It doesn’t actually set headers on the website.

If this is the case, how would I set the headers so that when the servers are the request they can actually interact with the header values.

I don’t want to create an API call- I just need it so that all subsequent requests contain my custom headers… how would you go about this?

Comment: You want to modify all subsequent requests using what method of sending the request?  Using the `fetch()` interface?  Using the `XMLHttpRequest` interface?  Using a library such as Axios?  Using your own custom API for making a request?

Comment: Your current attempt doesn't work because all it does is create a Headers object, but that Headers object is never used with any request.

Comment: yes I see that @jfriend00… I am wondering how I can set those headers so that when the `location.reload()` is called, the request can be sent with those headers… I mentioned I do not want to use any api

Comment: There is no way to do that.  You have no control over what happens with `location.reload()`.  Requests initiated from the URL bar or from `location.reload()` get the default headers from the browser.  Other than perhaps a browser plug-in, there is no way to influence those from within a web page.

Comment: Persistent authentication is typically handled via a cookie which you can set in the browser via Javascript from within a web page or can set on the server and which the browser will then send with future requests to that same host.